# Does passing passwords as plain text arguments reduce WiFi network security?

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless, security

[This app](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) uses the command line to create a WiFi access point with this command:

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint
```

and you can also make a WPA + WPA2 network with this command:

```
create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

but to do this you are entering the password, and it is in the terminal in plain text.

It can of course be removed from history, or never added by prepending a space to the command, but it is still typed in and is listed untill you close that terminal.

My question is if this is less secure than setting up a WiFi network with a GUI app that doesn't store it in the same way.

Comment: So... the attacker has access to your system?

Comment: @muru well if they did they can do anything can't they. I'm wondering if it could be reverse engineered easier? I'm not sure how the code works.

Comment: but the command and the arguments are all local to your system, even if it sets up the WiFi. Can the attacker peek over your shoulder to look at the screen? Without some form of access to the system, I don't see how it makes a difference. Your WiFi is still protected by WPA2 (presumably) with that key.

Comment: @Tim: As you're a reputation 10K user: If the below answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

Anything that is passed as a command line parameter can be viewed by:

- anyone who can see the terminal contents while they still are on screen (as you said);
- any program that has access to your history file until you remove it from there, or if you prevent it from being written (as you said);
- **any user** on the system that lists the processes using ps or similar tools.

It is bad practice.

Quoting from the page you linked to: "You can pass your SSID and password **through pipe** or through arguments (see examples).". Adapting from https://github.com/oblique/create_ap#wpa--wpa2-passphrase-using-pipe:

- Create a file that holds your password and make it readable only by your user:

  ```
  touch ~/.wifipass
  chmod 600 ~/.wifipass
  ```
- Write into it:

  ```
  MyAccessPoint
  MyPassPhrase
  ```
- Run the app with:

  ```
  cat ~/.wifipass | create_ap wlan0 eth0
  ```

This solves the problem of passing passwords through CLI arguments.

If you also want to encrypt the password as it is stored, you can use the gnome keyring: https://kparal.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/command-line-access-to-gnome-keyring/ and https://github.com/kparal/gkeyring This should ask for a password when you log in.

Comment: If we consider passing a password to an executable as a security issue in case the password gets stored into the command history (which it definetly can be), then it's exactly as dangerous to store it into a plain text file. No difference at all.

Comment: You missed the part where I said it has the advantage of not being viewed by **other users** on the system that list the process with ps. But thanks for the -1.

Comment: No, I didn't miss that, I rather missed the last link. Removed since you're not really advising to store a password in plain text, but anyway, what's the point of storing it? Why don't just `<<<password create_ap wlan0 eth0`, `<<EOF create_ap wlan0 eth0; password; EOF` or  `echo pasword | create_ap wlan0 eth0` (with a space at the beginning of each command)?

Comment: (and `reset` afterwards of course)